# How to print selected columns separated by tabs?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a txt file with columns separated by tabs and based on that file, I want to create a new file that only contains information from some of the columns.

This is what I have now:

```
awk '{ print $1, $5 }' filename > newfilename
```

That works except that when column 5 contains spaces e.g `123 Street`, only `123` shows up and the street is considered as another column.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the [field separator](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators) as tab:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ; { print $1, $5 }' filename > newfilename
```

Or [from the command line](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Command-Line-Field-Separator.html) like this:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ print $1, $5 }' filename > newfilename
```

Answer (score 4):

What about simple **cut** shell comand?

very simple yet does the job

```
cut -d "\t" -f 1,5 filename > newfilename
```

Comment: I think it should be `$'\t'`

Comment: it also doesn't work if the order of the columns is not ascending, I would stick to awk

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash syntax in the following way:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -a cols; do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "${cols[0]}" "${cols[4]}";
done < in.txt > newfile.txt
```

This will save 1st and 5th columns separated by tabs into the new file.